# Django object used with escapejs and truncatechars

Tags: python, django

I have an object in template:

```
               {{cwistassign.name|escapejs | truncatechars: 20}}
```

I want to use escapejs along with truncate but it is giving me an error:

```
               truncatechars requires 1 arguments, 0 provided
```

Is there any way I can use both for this object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to remove the space after `truncatechars:`

```
{{cwistassign.name|escapejs | truncatechars:20}}
```

will work!

Answer (score 0):

You have a white space,

do it:

```
{{cwistassign.name|escapejs | truncatechars:20}}
```